# How do I access an attachment from raw multipart/mixed POST request with PHP?

Tags: php, http, post, request

I have an API endpoint the receives a multipart/mixed POST. The contents are an XML file and a PDF as an attachment. I am able to separate the 2 parts from the raw request data, and can pull out and parse the XML.

How do I access the PDF attachment? Or, is my attempt the correct method and I have an error in that logic? (I can post this part of my code if needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was overthinking this problem; the solution is much more simple than my original attempts.

I separated the parts sent via http POST request to my app into $blocks[] (separated using the boundary sent in the Content_Type header)
I looped through $blocks[] and handled each type by looking at the first few bytes.
For the PDF block I used `preg_match('/(%PDF.*)/s', $block, $matches);` then wrote the contents of $matches[1] to a file.
Here is the block of code that writes the PDF:

```
//get the filename
preg_match('/filename=\"(.*)/', $block, $matches);
$filename = $matches[1];
$filename = rtrim(trim($filename), '"');

preg_match('/(%PDF.*)/s', $block, $matches);
$PDFDecoded = $matches[1];
$directory = 'path/to/store/PDFs';
$PDFfile = $directory . $filename;
$pdf = fopen($PDFfile, 'w'); //if you are on Windows, you may need 'wb'
fwrite($pdf, $PDFDecoded);
fclose($pdf);
```

I hope this helps someone.